# How to route TCP traffic through Tor proxy?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, tor, netcat

I would like to create a TCP connection using python library **socket**. This traffic should be redirected through Tor network but **socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure** is given.

The code below can connect to Tor proxy and gives a new Tor IP.

```
from stem.control import Controller
from stem import Signal
import socket
import socks

if __name__ == "__main__":
        with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
            # Creatting TOR connection
            controller.authenticate(password='password')
            controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
    
            socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "192.168.1.148", 9050)
            socket.socket = socks.socksocket
            
            # Creatting socket connection
            new_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            host = '192.168.1.148'
            port = 50007
    
            new_socket.connect((host, port))
            new_socket.sendall('Hello world')
            print(new_socket.recv(1024))
```

This is the error given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socks.py", line 809, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socks.py", line 443, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    self.proxy_peername, self.proxy_sockname = self._SOCKS5_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socks.py", line 533, in _SOCKS5_request
    raise SOCKS5Error("{:#04x}: {}".format(status, error))
socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/keylogger-project/./tor_proxy_connection.py", line 74, in <module>
    tor.__testing_socket_availability__()
  File "/home/pi/keylogger-project/./tor_proxy_connection.py", line 66, in __testing_socket_availability__
    self.socket.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socks.py", line 47, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socks.py", line 814, in connect
    raise GeneralProxyError("Socket error", error)
socks.GeneralProxyError: Socket error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure
```

Server side is a simple **nc -lvp 50007**

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>         socket.socket = socks.socksocket
>         ...
>         host = '192.168.1.148'
>         ...
>         new_socket.connect((host, port))
> ```

The target `192.168.1.148` is an IP address reserved for [private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) and thus not reachable from the internet. But the nodes on the Tor network are on the internet and thus cannot reach the given target.